# How do I alpha blend two images in Go?

Tags: image, go

I have two image.RGBA objects:  the background and the text layer.  The text layer will be anti-aliased, and may have text in different colors.  What I want is:

```
draw.Draw(bgLayer, bgLayer.Bounds(), textLayer, image.ZP, draw.OneMinusSrcAlpha)
```

Unfortunately, this is not an option.  draw.Src obviously just overwrites the pixel.  draw.Over is the same as draw.Src when the alpha channel is 255.  When it is < 255, then the pixel acts as (0, 0, 0, alpha), so the color information disappears.  It looks like they want me to use a mask, which means I'd have to create another image, and do the math on all the pixels myself;  in that case, I might as well just write my own Draw function that does what I want.

I assume I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't found it in either the documentation or on Google yet.

Comment: Can't you use same text layer as Src and also as mask to draw.Over?

Comment: Hmm, that seems be what I need.  I thought the mask had to be only one channel, but I guess not.